# The CDF of a summation of random variables with order statistics

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

Suppose I have the random variables $Z_k=X_k/Y_k$ with a PDF $f_{Z_k}(z_k)$ for $k=1,\,2\,\ldots, K$, where $\{X_k, Y_k\}$ are i.i.d. random variables. I can find

$$\text{Pr}\left[\sum_{k=1}^3Z_k\leq \eta\right]$$

as

$$\int_{z_3=0}^{\eta}\int_{z_2=0}^{\eta-z_3}\int_{z_1=0}^{\eta-z_3-z_2}f_{Z_1}(z_1)f_{Z_2}(z_2)f_{Z_3}(z_3)\,dz_1dz_2dz_3$$

Now suppose I arrange the random variables $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^K$ as

$$X_{(1)}\leq X_{(2)}\leq \cdots \leq X_{(K)}$$

and define $G_k=X_{(k)}/Y_{i_k}$, where $i_k$ is the index of the $k^{\text{th}}$ order statistic.

How can I find

$$\text{Pr}\left[\sum_{k=1}^3G_k\leq \eta\right]$$

Comment: The summations don't use the summation index; $\sum_{i=1}^3Z_k=3Z_k$; that's probably not what you meant?

Comment: Are $X_k$ and $Y_k$ independent?

Comment: @joriki You are right, the summation must be over k not i. A typo.

Comment: @drhab Yes, they are independent.